# Visual Studio 2010 web deployment to IIS server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I need to be able to setup my IIS server to accept Web Application publishing via the web deployment tool in Visual Studio 2010.  I have attempted to install web deploy, but still haven't had any success.  I am not positive if this is the right tool or not.

I am running Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
X64

IIS Version 7.5.7600.16385

SQL Databases will be accessed and are housed on this server as well.

SSRS is also running on this server.

Thank you,

Stephen Hathaway

Comment: Please add more details to your question, like what do you see, when "haven't had any success", how did you try to "publishing via the web deployment tool".

Comment: Error 1 Web deployment task failed.(Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://bfufsdbfcrpt1:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=HomeFinding'.)

Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'https://bfufsdbfcrpt1:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=HomeFinding'.
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.  0 0 Homefinding

Comment: Above is the error message I get.  When I went through the web deploy install, there wasn't anyplace to set or configure anything.  So I am not sure that I have the service URL or sitename correct.   This is a first time deployment of the application, so site does previously exist.  Servername is bfufsdbfcrpt1

Comment: Check this link [Common Web Deploy connection errors (and recipes for fixing them)](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2010/09/22/common-web-deploy-connection-errors-and-recipes-for-fixing-them.aspx)